# Showing $\operatorname{Cov}\left(\bar{X}_n,\frac{1}{n}\sum|X_i-\bar{X}_n|\right)=0$ for i.i.d standard normal $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, covariance, expected-value

Show that for $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ i.i.d. standard normal,

$$\operatorname{Cov}\left(\bar{X}_n,\frac{1}{n}\sum|X_i-\bar{X}_n|\right)=0$$ where $$\bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$$

What I do first is to write

$$\operatorname{Cov}\left(\bar{X}_n,\frac{1}{n}|X_i-\bar{X}_n|\right) = \frac{1}{n}E\left(\bar{X}_n \cdot\sum|X_i-\bar{X}_n|\right)-\frac{1}{n}E(\bar{X}_n)E\left(\sum|X_i-\bar{X}_n|\right)$$

Now, I now that the second part is zero, since $E(X_i)=0$ but then, I have no idea what to do with the absolute values in the first part. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since \begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}\left(\overline X_n,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i-\overline X_n|\right)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Cov}\left(\overline X_n,|X_i-\overline X_n|\right)
\end{align}, I think you can follow the procedure here to continue: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824547/prove-operatornamecov-overlinex-n-x-j-overlinex-n-0-for-indepen/.

Comment: well, but it's different. I don't know how to get rid of the absolute value

Answer (score 1):

Since the expectation $\mathbb E\left(\bar{X}_n \cdot|X_i-\bar{X}_n|\right)$ exists, to prove that it equals zero it is sufficient to prove that $\bar{X}_n \cdot|X_i-\bar{X}_n|$ has symmetric distribution. Take $Y_i=-X_i$ and make sure that $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are also i.i.d. standard normal, so the distribution of $\bar{Y}_n \cdot|Y_i-\bar{Y}_n|$ is the same as the distribution of $\bar{X}_n \cdot|X_i-\bar{X}_n|$, and 
$$
\bar{Y}_n \cdot|Y_i-\bar{Y}_n|=-\left(\bar{X}_n \cdot|X_i-\bar{X}_n|\right). 
$$

Comment: thanks. I still fail to see how this helps though

Comment: This helps to show that $\mathbb E\bar{X}_n \cdot|X_i-\bar{X}_n|=0$.

Comment: I don't see immediately how that works. Can you give me a step inbetween? We substitute the $X$s with $-Y$s but what does this do for the absolute value or the expectation?

Comment: The distribution of $X$ is symmentric if $X$ and $-X$ are identically distributed.